# Python function that takes an input and spits out a month and how many days it has

Tags: python

So if user inputs 2 it would spit out February, 28 and if 3 March, 31 etc. Needless to say I am new to python and this is the first function I have tried to write. I don't know if I can get the variables to respond to user input or this works

```
def dates(month ):
  1="Jan,31"
  2="Feb,28"
  3="Mar,31"
    print(  month )


def main():
   userin = input("Enter a number: ")
  month(userin)

main()
```

Comment: You need to pass the year too, because of february month for leap year

Comment: did you assign a string to a number?!

Comment: Please make sure your indentation is at the same level (don't mix tabs and spaces if you are) - Python depends on indentation. Also, I highly recommend following the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guidelines in your code - it will make it more readable. For example, there shouldn't be a space after the `month` parameter in your `dates` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `calendar` module; the [`calendar.monthrange()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) returns a `(weekday, number_of_days)` tuple:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> print calendar.monthrange(2012, 2)[1]
29
```

Note that you have to include the year; in a leap-year, February has 29 days, after all.

You can get *just* the current year with the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
year = datetime.date.today().year
```

Now you only have to ask for a month number:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def main():
    year = datetime.date.today().year
    userin = int(raw_input("Enter a month as number: "))  # Python 3: `int(input(...))` 
    print '{}, {}'.format(calendar.month_abbr[userin], calendar.monthrange(year, userin)[1])
```

This prints the abbreviated month and the number of days:

```
Enter a month as number: 2
Feb, 28
```

Comment: Wow I was really twisted up thanks for straitening me out guys.

Comment: It is very useful but I still need it to print out the name of the month along with the number of days so entering 2 puts out February, 28 i have a chance to sit and work on it now so thats what Ill be doing

Comment: @ChingOwn: Then use the `calendar` module some more; [`calendar.month_name`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) is a list of month names. `print calendar.month_name[userin]` is all that is needed here.

Comment: okay that works I was trying to import the month_name again   Like  from calendar import month_range. Thank you for your help ill follow your link, and accept the answer